# Has anyone used pubchemdb? Any similar API?

Tags: java, api, ncbi, pubchem

**Update: The link in the answer is both interesting and useful, but unfortunately does not address the need for a java API, so I am still looking forward to any input.**

I'm building a database of chemical compounds. I need all the synonyms (IUPAC and common names) as well as safety data for each.
I'll be using the freely available data at PubChem (http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/)

There's an easy way of querying each compound with simple HTTP gets. For example, to obtain glycerol data, the URL is:

```
http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/summary/summary.cgi?cid=753
```

And the following URL would return an easy to parse format:

```
http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/summary/summary.cgi?cid=753&disopt=DisplaySDF
```

but it will respond only very basic info, lacking safety data and only a few common names.

There is one public domain API for JAVA that seems a very complete, developed by a group at Scripps ([citation](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/27/5/741.short?rss=1)). The code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/pubchemdb/).

Unfortunately, this API is not very well documented and it's quite difficult to follow due to the complexity of the data involved.
For what I gathered, pubchemdb is using the [PubChem Power User Gateway (PUG) XML API](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug/pughelp.html)

Has anyone used this API (or any other one available)? I would appreciate a short description or tutorial on how to start with it.

Comment: This is probably a bit specialist for StackOverflow. Are there any cheminformatics communities you could try?

Comment: @Tom it might be quite specialized, but I'm hoping somebody here worked with these databases. There are quite a few ncbi questions answered here. I may contact the authors directly also.

Answer (score 2):

The [Cactvs Chemoinformatics toolkit](http://www.xemistry.com/academic) (free for academic/educational use) has full PubChem integration. Using the scripting environment, you can easily do something like

```
cactvs>ens create 753

ens0

cactvs>ens get ens0 E_NAMESET

PROPANE-1,2,3-TRIOL GLYCEROL 8043-29-6 29796-42-7 30049-52-6 37228-54-9 75398-78-6 78630-16-7 8013-25-0 175385-78-1 25618-55-7 64333-26-2 56-81-5 {Tegin M} LS-1377 G8773_SIGMA 15523_RIEDEL {Glycerin, natural} NCGC00090950-03 191612_ALDRICH 15524_RIEDEL {Glycerol solution} L-glycerol 49767_FLUKA {Biodiesel impurity} 49770_FLUKA 49771_FLUKA NCGC00090950-01 49927_FLUKA Glycerol-Gelatine G7757_SIAL GOL D-glycerol G9012_SIAL {Polyhydric alcohols} c0066 MOON {NSC 9230} G2025_SIGMA ZINC00895048 49781_FLUKA {Concentrated glycerin} {Concentrated glycerin (JP15)} D00028 {Glycerin (JP15/USP)} 44892U_SUPELCO {Glycerin, concentrated (JAN)} CRY 49782_FLUKA NCGC00090950-02 G6279_SIAL W252506_ALDRICH G7893_SIAL {Glycerin, concentrated} 33224_RIEDEL Bulbold Cristal Glyceol G9281_SIGMA Glycerol-1,2,3-3H G1901_SIGMA G7043_SIGMA 1,2,3-trihydroxypropane 1,2,3-trihydroxypropanol glycerin G2289_SIAL G9406_SIGMA {Glycerol-[2-3H]} CHEBI:17754 Glyzerin Oelsuess InChI=1/C3H8O3/c4-1-3(6)2-5/h3-6H,1-2H {90 Technical glycerine} Dagralax {Glycerin, anhydrous} {Glycerin, synthetic} Glycerine Glyceritol {Glycyl alcohol} Glyrol Glysanin NSC9230 Ophthalgan Osmoglyn Propanetriol {Synthetic glycerin} {Synthetic glycerine} Trihydroxypropane Vitrosupos {WLN: Q1YQ1Q} Glycerol-1,3-14C {4-01-00-02751 (Beilstein Handbook Reference)} AI3-00091 {BRN 0635685} {CCRIS 2295} {Caswell No. 469} {Citifluor AF 2} {Clyzerin, wasserfrei [German]} {EINECS 200-289-5} {EPA Pesticide Chemical Code 063507} {FEMA No. 2525} {Glicerina [DCIT]} {Glicerol [INN-Spanish]} {Glycerin (mist)} {Glycerin [JAN]} {Glycerin mist} {Glycerine mist} Glycerinum {Glycerolum [INN-Latin]} Grocolene {HSDB 492} IFP {Incorporation factor} 1,2,3-Propanetriol C00116 Optim {Propanetriol (VAN)} {1,2,3-PROPANETRIOL, HOMOPOLYMER} {Glycerol polymer} {Glycerol, polymers} {HL 80} {PGL 300} {PGL 500} {PGL 700} Polyglycerin Polyglycerine Polyglycerol {Unigly G 2} {Unigly G 6} G5516_SIGMA MolMap_000024

cactvs>
```

This hides all PUG ugliness - but in any case, I dare say that PUG *is* well documented. The toolkit goes much beyond simple data downloads - you can even open and query PubChem like a local SD file if you want to.

PubChem does not contain safety data, though. And safety data is country/region-dependent, strictly regulated, and you should be really careful not to be hit with liabilities. Have your approach checked by legal personnel!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I downloaded cactvs pdf documentation and I will go over it. It looks very interesting.